# tomcat10 does not deploy spring-boot 3 application

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat

I try to deploy spring 3 in a containerized tomcat10 server but the application does not deploy without any errors.

output of catalina.out:

> ATALINA_BASE:   /usr/local/tomcat
> Using CATALINA_HOME:   /usr/local/tomcat
> Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /usr/local/tomcat/temp
> Using JRE_HOME:        /opt/java/openjdk
> Using CLASSPATH:       /usr/local/tomcat/bin/bootstrap.jar:/usr/local/tomcat/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
> Using CATALINA_OPTS:
> 11-Sep-2023 17:27:40.758 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server version name:   Apache Tomcat/10.1.11
> 11-Sep-2023 17:27:40.761 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server built:          Jul 6 2023 13:45:39 UTC
> 11-Sep-2023 17:27:40.761 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server version number: 10.1.11.0
> 11-Sep-2023 17:27:40.761 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Name:               Linux
> 11-Sep-2023 17:27:40.761 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Version:            6.2.0-31-generic
> 11-Sep-2023 17:27:40.762 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Architecture:          amd64
> 11-Sep-2023 17:27:40.762 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Java Home:             /opt/java/openjdk
> 11-Sep-2023 17:27:40.762 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Version:           17.0.8+7
> 11-Sep-2023 17:27:40.762 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Vendor:            Eclipse Adoptium
> 11-Sep-2023 17:27:40.762 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_BASE:         /usr/local/tomcat
> 11-Sep-2023 17:27:40.762 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_HOME:         /usr/local/tomcat
> 11-Sep-2023 17:27:40.768 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/usr/local/tomcat/conf/logging.properties
> 11-Sep-2023 17:27:40.768 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
> 11-Sep-2023 17:27:40.768 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048
> 11-Sep-2023 17:27:40.768 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs=org.apache.catalina.webresources
> 11-Sep-2023 17:27:40.768 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dorg.apache.catalina.security.SecurityListener.UMASK=0027
> 11-Sep-2023 17:27:40.768 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: --add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED
> 11-Sep-2023 17:27:40.769 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: --add-opens=java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED
> 11-Sep-2023 17:27:40.769 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: --add-opens=java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED
> 11-Sep-2023 17:27:40.769 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: --add-opens=java.base/java.util.concurrent=ALL-UNNAMED
> 11-Sep-2023 17:27:40.769 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: --add-opens=java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport=ALL-UNNAMED
> 11-Sep-2023 17:27:40.769 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=/usr/local/tomcat
> 11-Sep-2023 17:27:40.769 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=/usr/local/tomcat
> 11-Sep-2023 17:27:40.769 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.io.tmpdir=/usr/local/tomcat/temp
> 11-Sep-2023 17:27:40.772 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent Loaded Apache Tomcat Native library [2.0.4] using APR version [1.7.0].
> 11-Sep-2023 17:27:40.775 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.initializeSSL OpenSSL successfully initialized [OpenSSL 3.0.2 15 Mar 2022]
> 11-Sep-2023 17:27:40.933 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
> 11-Sep-2023 17:27:40.960 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load Server initialization in [300] milliseconds
> 11-Sep-2023 17:27:40.997 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal Starting service [Catalina]
> 11-Sep-2023 17:27:40.998 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/10.1.11]
> 11-Sep-2023 17:27:41.019 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deploying web application archive [/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/dpok-ws.war]
> 11-Sep-2023 17:27:42.362 INFO [main] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
> 11-Sep-2023 17:27:42.517 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deployment of web application archive [/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/dpok-ws.war] has finished in [1,497] ms
> 11-Sep-2023 17:27:42.519 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
> 11-Sep-2023 17:27:42.525 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in [1565] milliseconds
> ^C11-Sep-2023 17:27:53.644 INFO [Thread-1] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.pause Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
> 11-Sep-2023 17:27:53.649 INFO [Thread-1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.stopInternal Stopping service [Catalina]
> 11-Sep-2023 17:27:53.658 INFO [Thread-1] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.stop Stopping ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
> 11-Sep-2023 17:27:53.661 INFO [Thread-1] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.destroy Destroying ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]

Here is my application pom:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.2</version>
        <relativePath/>
        <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.citadelle</groupId>
    <artifactId>dpok-ws</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>dpok-ws</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.citadelle</groupId>
            <artifactId>cit-security</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.ulisesbocchio</groupId>
            <artifactId>jasypt-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <distributionManagement>
        <repository>
            <id>NexusServer</id>
            <name>Internal Releases</name>
            <url>http://34.199.85.94:8081/repository/maven-citadelle-release/</url>
        </repository>
        <snapshotRepository>
            <id>NexusServer</id>
            <name>Internal Snapshots</name>
            <url>http://34.199.85.94:8081/repository/maven-citadelle-snapshot/</url>
        </snapshotRepository>
    </distributionManagement>
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>prod</id>
            <properties>
                <spring.profiles.active>prod</spring.profiles.active>
            </properties>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
                    <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
                    <version>10.2.1.jre17</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>test</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <spring.profiles.active>test</spring.profiles.active>
            </properties>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
                    <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
                    <scope>runtime</scope>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
    <build>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <url>https://proxy.citadelle-tools.com:48443/manager/text</url>
                    <path>/${project.artifactId}</path>
                    <server>tomcat10CitprodL</server>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.github.ulisesbocchio</groupId>
                <artifactId>jasypt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.4</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

and the pom of the security lib it is using:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.6</version>
        <relativePath />
        <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.citadelle</groupId>
    <artifactId>cit-security</artifactId>
    <version>1.8.0</version>
    <name>cit-security</name>
    <!-- FIXME change it to the project's website -->
    <url>https://www.groupecitadelle.com/</url>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <distributionManagement>
        <repository>
            <id>NexusServer</id>
            <name>Internal Releases</name>
            <url>http://34.199.85.94:8081/repository/maven-releases/</url>
        </repository>
        <snapshotRepository>
            <id>NexusServer</id>
            <name>Internal Snapshots</name>
            <url>http://34.199.85.94:8081/repository/maven-snapshots/</url>
        </snapshotRepository>
    </distributionManagement>
</project>
```

Note that the application is launched correctly when launched with tomcat embeded tomcat server:
mvn spring-boot:run

I tried to run my application in a container with the latest version of tomcat
Here is the dockerfile I used:

```
FROM tomcat:10.1.11
ADD dpok-ws.war /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/
```

I expected the application to be up and running but tomcat did not deploy with no errors instead.

Comment: I would recommend reversing the relationship.  Don't package your Spring app as a WAR and deploy it on Tomcat.  Better to create an executable Spring Boot JAR and run its internal Tomcat/Netty server.  You should be running JDK 17 or higher; JDK 11 is out of date.

Comment: Running the embeded tomcat server already work. I use this solution as temporary fix. But I need all my application to be availble under the same port behind tomcat. with the temporary fix I have my tomcat running on some port and another port open just for the embeded tomcat. This is not ideal for me.

Comment: No need for that.  You're doing it wrong.

Comment: How would you do it then?

Comment: "But I need all my application to be available under the same port behind tomcat." - I don't understand this.  Figure this out and you've got it.

Comment: Ok, I need to give more context. My applications are deployed on a server managed by a third party company. If I cannot put my applications behind tomcat this means that except there is another solution, I have to run embeded server of each of the application and ask to open a new port for each.

Comment: No, each application should have its own namespace and URL.  They can all use the same port e.g. http://X:80 and http://Y:80 are two separate applications.  Both use port 80.  No interference.

Comment: Agree this is how my non springboot 3 run. But Since I cannot make it work under my tomcat sever I run embeded tomcat of my application. Embeded tomcat server can obviously not use tomcat server port.

Comment: @duffymo I think I was not clear on my previous comments. I have to put it under tomcat server, because this is the solution my company chose I cannot change the way application are deployed because this one does not work under tomcat. More over managing X executable and run their internal tomcat server individually is not an viable option for production team.

Comment: @duffymo "No, each application should have its own namespace and URL. They can all use the same port e.g. X:80 and Y:80 are two separate applications. Both use port 80. No interference. – " 

Yes that is the whole point of putting each war under tomcat server else if you run inernal tomcat server separatly, then first process will take 80 for instance and the other will fail cause they won't be able to listen to port 80. If you put your application under tomcat then tomcat server can occupy port 80 and deploy each application on the same port but with different context hence my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to make main class extend SpringBootServletInitializer. I also overrided configure method.